# Define choices for inherited column in SharePoint list using Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, list-definition

I'm new to SharePoint development and I am trying to create a simple issue tracker for our IT team.

I'm trying to develop a sandboxed solution to deploy to SharePoint Online (O365), which contains a custom content type and list definition based on the "Issue" content type.

This all works fine, but I need to know how to modify the default status choices within my content type / list definition, and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

The default choices are: Active/Resolved/Closed.  I would like them to be: Open/Assigned/In Progress/Closed.

Please note that I understand how to change the choices in SharePoint after the list definition is deployed, but I'd like to define them within my Visual Studio project so that when I deploy the solution, the choices are already set up properly.

Comment: Okay, so after discussing this with a friend on Facebook, I've come up with two possible solutions.

1) I could create an EventReceiver that fires when the feature is activated that will modify the "Issue Status" site column to load the desired values.

or

2) I can hide the inherited site column and replace it with a custom column that contains my desired choices.

Since I only want these status choices to apply to my custom content type, solution 2 makes the most sense.

I'll post this as an answer when StackOverflow no longer prevents it  unless I hear a better solution before then.

Comment: Found where I can modify the choices in the schema.xml file for the list definition, which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can modify the schema.xml file for the list definition and define the choices there.